# PHP foreach combine_array - Same value problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an invoice app with php&mysql. 
My problem after submit an invoice I want to decrement quantity row. I'm almost done with this code

html

```
<input type="text" name="qty[]" class="productQty"/>
<input type="text" name="product_id[]" class="productId" readonly/>
```

php

```
<?php 
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");
if (!$result1) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
$qty = $_POST["qty"];
$qtys = array_values($qty);
$id= $_POST["product_id"];
$ids = array_values($id);
foreach (array_combine($qtys, $ids) as $id => $qty) {
    $show_id =  $id;
    $quantity =  $qty;
    echo "<p><b>" . $show_id . "</b></p>";
    echo "<p><b>" . $quantity . "</b></p>";
    /*
    $stock_update = "Update items set Stock= stock - '$quantity' where ID='$show_id'";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $stock_update)) {
        echo "stock done";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error();
    }
    */
}

?>
```

result 
1 
BKK01

2 
PEN01

but problem is if quantity value is equal. now result

1 
 
PEN01

can't show first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
foreach (array_combine($qtys, $ids) as $id => $qty) {
```

to :

```
foreach (array_combine($ids, $qtys) as $id => $qty) {
```

Your id and quantity are not in proper order. and also, I guess your id will be a unique one so there wont be any problem

```
array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )
```

Ref :http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php